# Localization of static HTML with i18next (loading local json translation files)

Tags: javascript, html, i18next

My project is HTML only. I am not going to use node or react version.

I've tried default example that works fine

```
 <div id="output" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/i18next/dist/umd/i18next.min.js"></script>
<script>
    i18next.init({
      lng: 'en',
      debug: true,
      resources: {
        en: {
          translation: {
            "key": "Hello World"
          }
        },
        de: {
          translation: {
            "key": "hello welt"
          }
        }
      }
    }, function(err, t) {
      // init set content
      updateContent();
    });

    function updateContent() {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = i18next.t('key');
    }

    function changeLng(lng) {
      i18next.changeLanguage(lng);
    }

    i18next.on('languageChanged', () => {
      updateContent();
    });
</script>
```

but I can't figure out how to load local json files instead of placing all translations in the js. Do I have to install an additional plugin for loading json translation files?

and is this the correct way of targeting every string in HTML?

```
function updateContent() {
  document.getElementById("homeTitle").innerHTML = i18next.t("home.title");
  document.getElementById("homeSubtitle").innerHTML = i18next.t("home.subtitle");
}
```

is there a way to add an attribute to HTML string like

```
<h1 data-i18n="home.title"></h1>
```

to get the translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load them with fetch, running a bunch of promises.
I wrote a [sandbox code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-knuth-kp0dx?file=/src/index.js) for you in vanilla JS.

*PS: Don't know why, but when you open code sandbox the code isn't executed well, you have to refresh the local preview to get it working (or you could try to open the preview from [here](https://kp0dx.csb.app/)), but I tested it via Live Server in my dev environment and it's working fine.*

Comment: Thank you for the help. Even I followed exact structure of your example but it worked only after I changed "/src/i18/" to "src/i18/".

Comment: the leading `/` stands for an absolute path. It will resolve your url from the root of your folder/domain, whilst without the leading it will resolve from your current location/url.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my question on how to work with namespaces. Any hint will be very helpful as I am new to this.

Comment: You should really open a new question as stack overflow is meant to be structured like an enciclopedia, one question per post :)

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help. I created a new question anyway.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68059830/localization-of-static-html-with-i18next-getting-the-translations