# Localization of static HTML with i18next (getting the translations)

Tags: javascript, html, i18next

I am using i18next to translate static content.
this is the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-knuth-kp0dx?file=/src/index.js)

```
<h1 id="homeTitle">Loading</h1>
<h1 id="homeSubTitle">Loading</h1>

<script>
function updateContent() {

  // Home
  document.getElementById("homeTitle").innerHTML = i18next.t("home.title");
  document.getElementById("homeSubTitle").innerHTML = i18next.t("home.subtitle");

}

/*function changeLng(lng) {
  i18next.changeLanguage(lng);
}*/

async function i18Loader() {
  const langs = ["en", "ru"];
  const jsons = await Promise.all(
    langs.map((l) => fetch("src/i18/" + l + ".json").then((r) => r.json()))
  );
  const res = langs.reduce((acc, l, idx) => {
    acc[l] = { translation: jsons[idx] };
    return acc;
  }, {});
  await i18next.init({
    lng: "en",
    debug: true,
    resources: res
  });
  updateContent();
  i18next.on("languageChanged", () => {
    updateContent();
  });
  const langSelector = document.getElementById("langSelector");
  langSelector.removeAttribute("disabled");
  langSelector.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    i18next.changeLanguage(e.target.value);
  });
}

i18Loader();
</script>
```

following this method I have to target every single string in my HTML with IDs.
I am wondering if there is a way to do this programmatically instead of targeting every string with

```
  document.getElementById("homeTitle").innerHTML = i18next.t("home.title");
  document.getElementById("homeSubTitle").innerHTML = i18next.t("home.subtitle");
  ...
```

Default documentation of i18next shows this method but this is not optimal for a case where there are hundreds of strings through out the paroject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could target every element with a certain class and read a property you set to get the i18 dictionary key for your element.
Here an example [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-knuth-kp0dx?file=/src/index.js&codemirror=1).

Something like this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("i18nelement");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const element = elements[i];
    const k = element.getAttribute("data-i18n");
    element.innerHTML = i18next.t(k);
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively there is also i18nextify: https://github.com/i18next/i18nextify

Comment: Hi there. You helped me with this question. Could you please see if you can help me with another point in the same code? 
here is my new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091841/store-selected-language-in-windows-localstorage
Really appreciate it.